# Create Function to select correct currency field from a table

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2014

I have some SQL that I think I could tidy up with a function but am not experienced in creating them.

My code has many sections that all look as follows:

```
ISNULL(SUM(Case  
when  @Currency = 'AED' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_AED 
when  @Currency = 'AUD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_AUD 
when  @Currency = 'BRL' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_BRL 
when  @Currency = 'CAD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_CAD
when  @Currency = 'CNY' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_CNY 
when  @Currency = 'EUR' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_EUR 
when  @Currency = 'GBP' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_GBP 
when  @Currency = 'HKD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_HKD 
when  @Currency = 'INR' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_INR 
when  @Currency = 'LYD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_LYD 
when  @Currency = 'QAR' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_QAR 
when  @Currency = 'SAR' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_SAR 
when  @Currency = 'SGD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_SGD 
when  @Currency = 'USD' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_USD 
when  @Currency = 'VEF' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_VEF 
when  @Currency = 'ZAR' And Flag = 'Current' then BILLED_ZAR 
End),0) As Total_Billed
```

This makes my code massively long and I'm hoping to shorten.  Can I create a function where I provide the @Currency parameter (that the user has selected when running the report) and get the correct BILLED value (for example).  So I would input into the function the @Currency, @Flag and @Field - in the example above 'BILLED_' to be suffixed with the right currency code.

I hope this makes sense - many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is not ANSI SQL.)

Comment: this just *screams* that you should have a column "Currency" in your table  and another one with the `Bill` value, instead of one column per currency. Or just a table with the currency conversion

Comment: Why you don't create a table and join  it ..?

Comment: Thanks @jarlh - SQL Server MS 2014 - you are talking to a self taught user - so open to corrections, etc :)

Comment: @Lamak - yes possibly - this is from a summary table in a data warehouse so currency conversion, etc all done as part of overnight load.

Comment: I'm usually not a fan, but at this point it seems like you should use dynamic sql instead of this `CASE` expression

Comment: Many thanks all - so if we say that changing the structure of the table is not possible - using dynamic SQL would be the preferable solution over a function - I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compact your code (a little) something like this.

```
isnull(sum(case Flag 
                when 'Current' then case @Currency
                      when 'AED' then BILLED_AED 
                      when 'AUD' then BILLED_AUD
                      --and so on
                      end
           end), 0) As Total_Billed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query..

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max)
DECLARE @Currency VARCHAR(50)='USD'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ISNULL(SUM( 
                       CASE WHEN ISNULL('+@Currency+','''')!='''' and Flag = ''Current''                    
                            THEN BILLED_'+@Currency+' END),0) AS As Total_Billed
                    FROM YourTable'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to keep a table of the currencies that are accepted so that the system can be scalable to include more currencies as they come. So you have a table like:

```
Table name: Accepted Currency

Currency

AED
AUD
BRL
CAD
CNY
EUR
GBP
HKD
INR
LYD
QAR
SAR
SGD
USD
VEF
ZAR
```

Based on the above table you can create a stored proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CurrencySelector]
(
    @Curr VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ISNULL(CONCAT('BILLED_', [Currency]), '0')
    FROM [Accepted Currency]
    WHERE Currency = @Curr
END
```

Execute this function only when you have the flag and other fields as per your requirements.